# Why python requests module not pulling the whole html?

Tags: python, web-scraping

The link: https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels

code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Tried also this:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels')
data = json.dumps(r.text)
print(data)
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="SOME_value">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its printing the html without the tag the data are in, only showing a single script tag.
How to access the data (shown in browsing view, looks like json)?[browsing view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGPg.png) [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7iIy.png) [code response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2jUo.png))

Comment: What is the data that you need ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the tag the data are in"? Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of an example of the exact tag you are looking for.

Comment: What you show is JSON, not HTML. There are no tags in JSON.

Comment: edited. Simply browsing through the link, the response is some json like texts. I want to get them. But in my python script, when requesting, the html is only showing a script tag within, nothing else

Comment: Please post text directly in your question, not screenshots.

Comment: After looking at this a bit more, I see your confusion. The response I see in the browser is totally different than the response from `requests.get()` in python. IDK why. One suggestion is to use another tool such as Postman to perform the request to see what you get that way.

Comment: Side note: there should be no reason to use `BeautifulSoup` since you expect the response to be JSON. You can just do `print(r.text)` in your example then show the output and how it is different than what you expect.

Comment: used bs4 just further navigating through the soup object simply. yes for all json format, its not necessary. I understand that.

Comment: "The response I see in the browser is totally different than the response from requests.get() in python." --- Exactly this is the confusion, its like am I missing something here?

Comment: I would try with `curl`, Postman or some other similar HTTP client that doesn't mess with the response like a browser does. That will let you see what the raw response is and maybe figure out what is going on here.

Comment: I think you have to get a JavaScript generated http cookie `tkrm_alpekz_s1.3-ssn`. This, along with the appropriate user-agent header (only certain values allowed), are required for json response.

Comment: Please add `print(r.status_code)` to your code. What does it show?

Comment: To see what is going on here: Open a new tab in your browser. Then open the developer tools and go to the Network tab (in Google Chrome press F12 to get there quickly). Then enter the URL in the new tab. You will see there are multiple requests and see more about what the browser is doing.

Comment: its showing 429

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this can be done...That data simply isn't in the `r.text`

If you do this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.prettify())
```

You get this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/ips.js?tkrm_alpekz_s1.3=0EOFte3LjRKv3iJhEEV2hrnisE5M3Lwy3ac3UPZ19zdiB49A6ZtBjtiwBqgKQN3q2MEQ3NbFjTWfmP9GqArOIAML6zTvSb4lRHD7FsmJFVWNkSwuTNWUNuJWv6hEXBG37DhBtTXFEO50999RihfPbTjsB">
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is no `<pre>` tag for whatever reason. So you're unable to access that.

I also get an [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) Error when accessing the URL:

`GET https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels 429`

What is the end goal here? Because this site doesn't seem to be willing to do anything. Some sites are unable to be parsed, for various reasons. If you're wanting to play with JSON data I would look into using an API instead.

If you google https://www.hyatt.com and manually go to the URL you mentioned you get a 404 error.

I would say Hyatt don't want you parsing their site. So don't!

Comment: ow. I thought there was something that I was missing.

Comment: "I also get an 429 Error when accessing the URL:" Which URL gives a 429? And what do you mean by "you google `https://www.hyatt.com` and manually go to the URL"? Which URL do you "manually" go to? And what do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: if you put `https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels` into something like postman you get a 429 error. If you manually type in `hyatt.com` and then continue to type `/explore-hotels/services/hotels` the page gives you a 404.

Answer (score 0):

The response is JSON, not HTML. You can verify this by opening the Network tab in your browser's dev tools. There you will see that the `content-type` header is `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

You can parse this into a useable form with the standard `json` package:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels')
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Still not working, i thought of this too.

Comment: @AhnafTanjid If you still need help, [edit] your question or post a new one showing more details, including the exact code you are running and output you get, including errors.

Comment: pretty sure you mean `data = json.loads(r.text)`, but if you are using requests anyway, you can just use the convenience method `data = r.json()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the correction and suggestion. I have to look up the requests functionality when I need it. It seems this isn't the problem. Somehow the python code gets an HTML response but the browser gets a JSON response. Still haven't figured out what is different.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga data=r.json() not working still :(

Comment: @AhnafTanjid I never implied it would work, I said it would be equivalent to `data = json.loads(r.text)`. Your problem is that the website is using javascript to get/render the information, it isn't serving it statically.

Comment: @AhnafTanjid this is often because people don't want that data scraped, but you can access it using something like a headless browser.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see 3 different behaviors between 1) entering https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels in my browser, 2) the python code in the OP, and 3) doing `curl --get https://www.hyatt.com/explore-hotels/service/hotels --output hotels`. This leads me to believe there is more going on here than JavaScript. I'm not sure what it is, though.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's a gzipped script, curl is just not automatically decompressing it. See the `.headers` in the response object with requests.

Comment: In my browser, I get the giant JSON blob that the script is rendering.  Sometimes I get 502 errors but if I refresh I'll get it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Exactly. That's what I was confused about at first. However, the JSON is the response of a different request. If you look at the nework tab, you can see the other requests.